# Proper Shutdown of SQL Servers in a Cluster

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-server

I was just wondering what the best approach should be for shutting down an Active/Active Cluster where both nodes need to be shutdown for disk maintenance.

I was thinking of this process:

1. Open Failover Cluster Manager
2. Right-click on the cluster name, select ‘More Actions’, then “Shut Down Cluster…”
3. When prompted if you are sure you want to shut down the cluster, click “Yes”
4. Shutdown both Nodes
5. Do Disk Maintenance
6. Power on both Nodes
7. Fail Cluster resources back to their preferred node

Does anyone see any issues with that? How do you ensure the Cluster Resources come back up on the correct node considering they'll come up at a different time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone see any issues with that?

You are correct in the steps but your approach is way too much for a little work.

**For disk maintenance, why would you shutdown the entire cluster ?**

Just suspend that disk (which requires maintenance) and then once it is done resume the node.

Basically, `SHUT DOWN CLUSTER` will stop all the roles and services on all the nodes of the cluster. The Cluster UI will ensure that all the roles and services are shutdown **gracefully**.

Seems like you have posted the same question at [SQLServerCentral.com](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/proper-shutdown-of-sql-servers-in-a-cluster-1)

Refer to [How to Properly Shutdown a Failover Cluster or a Node](https://web.archive.org/web/20160103232617/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/clustering/archive/2013/08/23/10443912.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going for proper sutdown
You should first stop application services, I hope you are talking about downtime.
Then you should stop SQL server services 
Now you can stop Cluster services server services. Although you wont need to shutdown whole cluster for disk maintenance